# Centering absolute element inside fixed width container

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed size parent with an image with and absolute element of text nested inside.

I would like the `.video-text` to center itself off the browser window size and not the fixed width of the parent div.

HTML:

```
<div class="video-bg">
    <img src="../images/video-bg.jpg" />
    <div class="video-text ">
       <a href="#"><h3> Watch the video to learn more</h3></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video-bg {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1280px;
}
.video-bg img {
    width: 100%;
}
.video-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 44%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Invalid html `<img src=..` missing `"` there.

Comment: So if I understand you, you want the video-text element be centered to the browser window always, regardless of the position of the parent?

Comment: @Shmeano66 Try to use `text-align: center` instead of `position: absolute`.

Comment: @Shmeano66 just so, I can give you an accurate answer are you trying to have video-bg be the background of the entire website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting position to static rather than relative.

An element with position: static; is not positioned in any special way; it is always positioned according to the normal flow of the page.

Comment: Perfect MooseMan. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Did that fix the bug completely?

Comment: The absolute object needed the margin to be adjusted off the entire page but it worked fine. Cheers

Comment: That's good to hear! Also, don't forget to mark your question as answered now that you have your bug fixed. :)